# My sql password

Tags: mysql

I am using command on Mac

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

anyone can help me

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu on the mac - or OSX?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p
```

or

```
mysqladmin -u root --password
```